# Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW -Final?

Tags: windows-mobile

Is the "Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW" a final version?

RTW? Release to Web? Does this mean that it is a non final release or does it mean that it is only being released to the web?

I am thinking that this is a pre-release version.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en#QuickDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "R" in RTW stands for "Release", so no, this is not a pre-release.  It is a full release, just to theg web.  RTM wouldn't make sense, as they're not shipping the SDKs, etc to manufacturers, but instead to the development community.

Comment: So RC, where "R" stands for "Release," is also not a pre-release?

Comment: RC is "Release Candidate".  Let's not get into teh semantics of modifiers - obviously a "Candidate" isn't a release.  If you go to the App Hub, the release points to that download.  If you go to Scott Guthries blog, who says the tools are released, it points to that download.  What more do you want as proof that it's a "release"?